# Propelorm 2 не удается создать schema.xml

Tags: mysql, framework

Поставил через composer propelorm 2. Через консоль пытаюсь создать схему БД, т.е. пишу в консоли

> vendor/bin/propel init

Дохожу до

> Do you have an existing database you want to use with propel? [no]:

Выдает

> [Propel\Runtime\Connection\Exception\ConnectionException]     Unable
>   to open connection
>   [Propel\Runtime\Adapter\Exception\AdapterException]     Unable to open
>   PDO connection   [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)

Бд MySQL, oc ubuntu 14.04

**Обновление**

При запросе

> Do you have an existing database you want to use with propel? [no]: :

Я пишу `yes`, т.е. я хочу создать схему для существующей БД. Перед этим на одном из шагов он запрашивает пароль, собственно это и не понятно, т.к. пишет когда пишет

> Please enter your database password:

Пароль подходит и все работает, что собственно и подтверждает сообщение

> Connected to sql server successful!

**Обновление 2**

После выполнения команды в терминале и ввода `Enter`

```
mysql -u имя_пользователя_бд -p
```

Получаю

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. Your MySQL
>   connection id is 198 Server version: 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input
>   statement.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вам же всё написали - пользователем root к БД без пароля подключиться невозможно. У вас либо не установлен MySQL сервер, либо не запущен, либо настроен так, что рут не может подключаться к нему без пароля.

**Обновление**

Напишите в консоли `mysql -u имя_пользователя_бд -p`, MySQL спросит пароль, введите его и нажмите Enter. Что произойдет?

**Обновление 2**

Окей, пароль подходит. Значит, Ваша проблема в том, что пользователь root должен подключаться к БД с паролем, а propel пытается подключаться без пароля. Укажите propel ваш пароль от рута БД.